# Install Fedora GNOME from the command line

Tags: fedora

I have a complicated [situation](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/48kuki/unable_to_install_fedora_23_with_a_btrfs/) where I can't install Fedora using the graphical installer.

> I have been using the following partition setup on Ubuntu for a number
>   of years:
>
> - `/dev/sda1`: VFAT EFI partition.
> - `/dev/sda4`: BTRFS Linux Boot partition.
> - `/dev/sda5`: LUKS Encrypted Disk
>
> Inside `/dev/sda5` is an LVM volume group with with two logical
>   volumes:
>
> - `/dev/mapper/vg-root`: A BTRFS partition.
> - `/dev/mapper/vg-swap`: A swap partition.
>
> I have two subvolumes on `/dev/mapper/vg-root`:
>
> - `@`: my root subvolume, which will be mounted at `/`.
> - `@home`: my home subvolume, which will be mounted at `/home`.
>
> For my purposes, this layout makes a lot of sense and works well.

The graphical Anaconda [won't let me use my BTRFS subvolume for `/`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJHJg.jpg), so I can't use it to install.

I have tried to use kickstarter to install things, but I can't because it won't let me install to preexisting LVM LVs, you can't specify `/dev/mapper/vg-root`

Failing all of this, is there a straightforward way to install Fedora Workstation into a specific local directory, which happens to be a bunch of mount points in the right places? I don't mind setting up fstab and crypttab and the like, I just want to install Fedora, $#@!